# Unwinnable klondike game

Tags: solitaire, klondike-solitaire

On an android app, called Classic Solitaire Klondike from Potato Jam, I'm struggling with a deck which seems unsolvable. In this app, 100% of the decks had a solution before.
I wrote a solver running every possible solution, but nothing comes out.
Here's a capture done with my solver:
[image]

I represented with red color the cards I never managed to flip. So I get stuck quite fastly.
In the app, the deck is identified by the following seed number: 43688966

I guess I must probably miss something, but can't see where ...

Comment: While I can't speak for that specific deal not all deals are winnable and not all apps guarantee that  every game will be winnable.

Comment: You're probably right. I knew about the classic win-rate on this kind of solitaire, but as I did a lot of game in this app and always found a solution, I assumed that was a design choice to propose a winnable deck. I asked on their play store reviews, and see what it gives.